# Cypress: How do I assert against the contents of a window.fetch POST request body?

Tags: javascript, sinon, cypress, sinon-chai

So say I've got a cypress test with a spy on `window.fetch` like so:

```
describe('My test', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000', {
        onBeforeLoad(win) {
            cy.spy(win, 'fetch')
        },
    })
```

I can assert that POST request has a certain URL like so:

```
cy.window().its('fetch').should('be.calledWith', 'http://whatever.com/stuff')
```

but I can't figure out how to assert against the body of that request. 
How would I assert, for instance, that it contains `my_param=10`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nobody eh? Well, if anyone else stumbles across this, I figured it out and here's how you do it:

```js
cy.window().its('fetch').should(
  'be.calledWithMatch', 
  'http://your-url.com/here', 
  sinon.match.has('body', sinon.match('your_param=expected_value')))
```

Remember to import sinon as a separate dependency.

You can use this line multiple times to assert against multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the answer of @BaronVonKaneHoffen:

There is no need for extra import, you can use the Cypress.sinon.match.

Here is a snippet, for window.open stubbing if somebody would looking for it:

```
cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')
})
```

...

...

```
cy.get('@open').should('have.been.calledWithMatch', Cypress.sinon.match('expected_value'))
```

I think for fetch you can steal some ideas from it, too :).